# Как реализовать AdMob в проект libgdx на Android Studio

Tags: java, android, libgdx

В общем, подключил:

```
 Project-level build.gradle 
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    ependencies {
           ...
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'
        }
...

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

В string.xml прописал

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

Что делать дальше? В libgdx нужно создать activity_main.xml?
А потом в главном классе прописать следующий код?

```
     MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

?
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В разделе AndroidLauncher нужно внести изменения, а именно: добавить контейнер для отображения рекламы:

```
    public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            RelativeLayout main_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            View gameView = initializeForView(new MainClass(), config);
            main_layout.addView(gameView);

            /**Тут непосредственно формируем место для банера*/

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            main_layout.addView(banner, adParams);

            /***/
            setContentView(main_layout);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("идентификатор_тестового_устройства").build();
            banner.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }
```

Более подробно [тут](http://olelucoye.ru/publ/libgdx/libgdx_i_admob/7-1-0-86)

Для включения/отключения баннера нужно использовать handler